# What is the best VISUAL RAD environment for building Web databases?

Tags: database, ide, rad

I am referring to a truly visual environment, and not something that claims to be visual but requires mountains of hand-coded script, or a code generator that farts out a Web site and leaves you to start editing in Visual Studio.  Are there any truly visual Web dev platforms out there?

Answer (score 2):

You might try FrontPage or something, but you would probably be better served becoming more comfortable with the code, or hiring a web developer to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Clarion products from Softvelocity are great round trip code generators. They have tools for ASP, PHP, and ASP.NET. I have only used their win32 tools with great results. Their tools are a bit pricey but well worth them in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

You might try an online forms-building service, such as [Wufoo](http://wufoo.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try something like [Microsoft Expression Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/) which for its capabilities seems to also be somewhat lightweight. I have the Web 2 edition installed and it works rather well.

Answer (score 0):

As Servio said above (can't Vote Up or Comment yet), but with some more info.

Clarion 6 + [Nettalk](http://capesoft.com/accessories/netsp.htm) provides template-driven rapid application development. You can create browse/form web systems very quickly.

- I'm the Clarion Evangelist ([Clarion Folk](http://clarionfolk.com)), so take this with a grain of salt.
- Have just realised there are no decent videos up showing Clarion 6 + Nettalk. Will remedy that shortly.

Cheers